# Add and Subtract Buttons on Bottle Generated Webpage

Tags: python, bottle

Currently I have a bottle app that reads elements from a sqlite database and displays them in a table (using beer because well... I like beer). I want to be able to adjust a number in the table (amount) using add and subtract buttons in the table row. The buttons should both update the amount in the database, and refresh the amount displayed on the page.

This is the python/bottle portion:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/display')
    def display():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('beers.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT id, brewer, beer, amount FROM beer;")
    result = c.fetchall()
    c.close()

    output = template('make_table', rows=result)
    return output
```

This is the current template, with the add and subtract buttons.

```
<p>The available beers are:</p>
<table border="1">
%for row in rows:
    <tr>
    %for col in row:
        <td>{{col}}</td>
    %end
        <td><input type ="button" value="Add"></td>
        <td><input type ="button" value="Subtract"></td>
    </tr>
%end
</table>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a Bottle question, per se. Sounds like you need some background on how to build a dynamic webapp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `/display` route with `POST` method.

In this, catch the value of beer's ID, and if the user clicked on Add or Sub.

Once this is done, you got the beer ID, and the action to do, you just have to do your stuff with DB, and redirect to the `/display` page.

Here's the Bottle App code :

```
@app.route('/display', method='POST')
def display_mod():
    #You get the value of each button : None if non clicked / Add or Sub if clicked
    add = request.POST.get('Add')
    sub = request.POST.get('Sub')
    # b_id is the ID of the beer the user's clicked on (either on add or sub)
    b_id = request.POST.get('beer_id')

    if add is not None:
        # do something
        redirect("/display")

    if sub is not None:
        # so something
        redirect("/display")
```

Then, change your template to include a form and change the two buttons in submit button. You also need to put an `hidden` input, so that you can pass the data to the app.

```
<p>The available beers are:</p>
<table border="1">
%for row in rows:
    <tr>
    <!-- Here you grab the beer's ID that you'll use later -->
    %p_id = row[0] 
    %for col in row:
        <td>{{col}}</td>
    %end
        <form action="/display" method="POST">
            <!-- input type hidden, and value is the ID of the beer -->
            <input type = "hidden" name ="beer_id" value= "{{p_id}}">
            <td><input type ="submit" name="Add" value="Add"></td>
            <td><input type ="submit" name="Sub" value="Subtract"></td>
        </form>
    </tr>
%end
</table>
```

And here you go. Hope it helps (if so, don't be shy, send me a beer !)

Comment: No problem, don't forget about my beer ! 
BTW : you really should read the Bottle doc, there's an amazing tutorial that can be done very quickly, you'll learn a lot there ;)